Looking for a non-fiction work about U.S. politics in the 21st century
Some time between 2006 and 2015 I read a book about contemporary U.S. politics. I was struck by the cogent description of the core values of Republicans (or perhaps conservatives in general) and how they differed from those of Democrats (or perhaps progressive politics in general), and I remember it listing things like the role of the father-figure in a family as one (of many) points of differentiation.
I think a key theme might have been the increasing focus by the Republicans on social values rather than economic issues, and I think it also covered some of the historic basis for this, e.g. the influence of the Moral Majority, etc. I think it might also have referenced the Tea Party movement, which puts its publication after 2009.
I've spent several years trying to track down the title, but there are so many books published on the topic of U.S. politics each year that I've found it impossible to wade through all of the possibilities.
I also seem to recall a reference to "the elephant in the room" and for some reason thought that this is where the metaphor first became popular (in hindsight: doh!), but I now think this may have been a reference within the book to another non-fiction work, The elephant in the room : evangelicals, libertarians, and the battle to control the Republican Party by Ryan Sager, published in 2006. Similar overall content, but the book I'm looking for definitely isn't Sager's Elephant: not only does Sager's lack the specific focus of the book I read, but Sager's book is only available as a hardback, whereas the one that I read was most likely a paperback (possibly trade / B-format). I have a vague recollection that it had a mostly white cover.

I haven't read this, so I don't know for sure, but perhaps it is The Righteous Mind, by Jonathan Haidt. I've seen it referenced several times with relation to ethical "value theory" as it pertains to twenty-first–century American politics. The idea as I understand it is that conservatives draw from values such as authority, loyalty, and purity in addition to the do-no-harm and equity values that progressives, well, value.
As for specific elements from your memory:

Google Books doesn't have previews for the pages including the word "father" so I can't comment on that (pp. 189–190 have a snippet suggesting a possible connection).
The Moral Majority is mentioned only once, on p. 12; the Tea Party a few times throughout.
I don't see any "elephant in the room" directly, but Haidt apparently originated (in The Happiness Hypothesis) the metaphor for the irrational/rational parts of the human mind being like an elephant and its rider: the rider influences, rather than controls, the elephant. Lots of occurrences of this idea in The Righteous Mind.


This is a very promising lead, and the cover does look familiar. Not quite enough detail for me to say "definitely yes" (and award a tick) – I think I need to track down an actual copy at a library – but thank you for giving me something to work on. I've upvoted, and hopefully a tick follows in a month or two...
